# How do I subscribe to property changed events raised from child objects?

Tags: winforms, linq, entity-framework-4, propertychanged

I have an Invoice object that exposes a readonly property - `Total`.  This total is just the sum of the total of the invoice items:

```
public decimal Total { get { return this.InvoiceItems.Sum(s => s.Total); } }
```

The Total property in the InvoiceItems class looks like this:

```
public decimal Total { get { return Price * Quantity - Discount; } }
```

The classes and properties were generated by LINQ (except for Total properties in both classes which I created myself).  When a price, for example, changes on an `InvoiceItem`, I would like the change to be reflected in the `Total` property of its parent `Invoice`.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to do this manually, i.e.

1. Iterate over the child `InvoiceItems`
2. Add a handler to their `PropertyChanged` event
3. When their `Price` property changes, update your `Total` property
4. *optionally* handle `CollectionChanged` event on `InvoiceItems` to add / remove `PropertyChanged` subscriptions as invoice items are added / removed.